# Why OpenLayers v6 can not show layers when they secured by GeoServer 2.17.2 GeoFence extension?

Tags: openlayers, geoserver-geofence

I have two workspaces in GeoServer and two different users in GeoServer. For each user I created a rule in GeoServer by GeoFence Extension, each user must be see and access to only own layers are inside own workspace, that allowed by GeoFence rule, however if I set GeoFence like below images OpenLayers can show layers but each user can see content of another user's worksapce also.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'd expect user 5f30ee36... can see only content of h0BUjvHBeM workspace, whereas it can see "Emeni" layers that is belong to j0BV2EjWBs workspace for user 5f5cd8...
However I can fix this problem by uncheck "Use GeoServer roles to geo authorization" and each user able to see only own layers are inside own workspaces, But my problem will happen after this step, "OpenLayers can not show layers!" but I can get link of layers! name of them and even see them in my browser (outside OpenLayers)"

My axios code is [here](https://pastebin.pl/view/346c565b)

sysinfo: Os:Debian 10 x64, Openlayers V6, GeoServer 2.17.2, GeoFence 2.17.x,

my [geoserver log](https://pastebin.pl/view/24de32df)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenLayers will by default send an anonymous request to the server.  To authorise as a specific user a WMS image request would need to be loaded by xhr with an appropriate request header using an `imageLoadFunction` (or `tileLoadFunction` if using tiled WMS).  The simplest method is to prompt for username and password when opening the page containing the OpenLayers map and use those variables in subsequent requests (although more secure methods such as OAuth2 can also be configured).

```
imageLoadFunction: function(image, src) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.open('GET', src);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + window.btoa(username + ':' + password));
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
    image.getImage().onload = function() {
      URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL);
    };
    image.getImage().src = objectURL;
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I'll do that as soon as possible, can I do that by fetch() method also? if it is possible, it would be great if you add your solution based on fetch() method also. I understand for my issue that would be enough if add your code to my openlayers code, right?

Comment: Fetch can be used instead of xhr.  If you set up username and password as globals then the code can be inserted into the ImageWMS source constructor.

Comment: Thank you so much, I add your code to my wmslayer in openlayers could you please check link https://pastebin.pl/view/35481d19 is  that correct form and true place I added?

Comment: I added your code, it worked excellent, But I can't get info, when I click on features

Comment: You will also need to set the request header when fetching GetFeatureInfo urls.